# Map array of strings to property in a List of objects C#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, list

I have List of objects `List<MyModel> myList`

MyModel.cs

```
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int SourceTitle {get; set;}
    public int Detail {get; set;}
    public string Color {get; set:}
```

I have an string array of colors ie.
 `string[] colorPallete[] = {color1, color2, color3, coloe4 ..... color10}`

Now, I have about 35 items in my list. There can be multiple items with same SourceTitle and Id. I want to assign a color to the items with the same SourceTitle. Ultimately when the count of my titles goes above 10, the 11th title should be assigned with the Color1 again.

Right now, I do it using Id as below :

```
myList.ForEach{x => x.Color = colorPallete.ElementAtOrDefault((x.Id -1) % colorPallete.Length));
```

This works fine, but if the remainder of two different Id's is same, they will be assigned the same color which is not what I want.

Is there a way I can assign the color in relation to the titles and not Ids?

Comment: Can an `ID` being duplicate, or only `SourceTitle`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```
SortedList<int, int> colorHistory = new SortedList<int, int>();
int k = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
{
    if (!colorHistory.ContainsKey(myList[i].SourceTitle))
    {
        colorHistory[myList[i].SourceTitle] = ++k % colorPallete.Length;
    }
    myList[i].Color = colorPallete[colorHistory[myList[i].SourceTitle]];
}
```

Output:

```
  ID    Source    Color
--------------------------
   0         5    color1
   1        19    color2
   2         8    color3
   3        15    color4
   4        12    color5
   5        15    color4
   6         3    color6
   7        16    color7
   8         3    color6
   9        17    color8
  10        18    color9
  11         8    color3
  12         4    color10
  13        13    color1
  14         4    color10
  15        18    color9
  16         4    color10
  17         3    color6
  18        14    color2
  19         1    color3
  20         3    color6
  21         4    color10
  22         6    color4
  23        17    color8
  24        13    color1
  25        17    color8
  26         8    color3
  27         6    color4
  28        18    color9
  29        13    color1
  30         2    color5
  31        11    color6
  32        18    color9
  33        19    color2
  34        19    color2
  35        10    color7
  36        13    color1
  37         5    color1
  38        11    color6
  39         2    color5
  40         2    color5
  41        10    color7
  42        12    color5
  43         2    color5
  44        13    color1
  45        12    color5
  46         2    color5
  47        18    color9
  48        14    color2
  49         6    color4
  50         8    color3
  51        11    color6
  52        14    color2
  53         3    color6
  54         7    color8
  55         1    color3
  56        14    color2
  57        10    color7
  58         3    color6
  59        15    color4
  60         7    color8
  61        16    color7
  62        17    color8
  63        10    color7
  64        15    color4
  65         7    color8
  66        10    color7
  67         4    color10
  68        14    color2
  69        13    color1
  70         5    color1
  71        18    color9
  72        12    color5
  73        12    color5
  74        19    color2
  75        12    color5
  76        12    color5
  77         4    color10
  78         5    color1
  79         1    color3
  80        16    color7
  81        10    color7
  82        12    color5
  83        13    color1
  84         5    color1
  85        11    color6
  86        17    color8
  87        16    color7
  88        13    color1
  89        19    color2
  90        15    color4
  91         3    color6
  92         3    color6
  93        15    color4
  94        15    color4
  95         5    color1
  96        13    color1
  97         3    color6
  98         7    color8
  99         6    color4
```

Comment: @helloworld I just slightly modified it for better performance. Please check again.

Comment: Downvoter, could you please kindly give a reason what is wrong with my answer? Otherwise your vote is poinless, as I don't know how to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var group in list.GroupBy(x => x.SourceTitle))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < group.Count(); i++)
    {
        group.ElementAt(i).Color = palette[i % 10];                        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this applies the same color to all the titles

Comment: No probs. Is this what you want? SourceTitle has a unique color unless there are more then 10?

                int counter = 0;
                foreach (var group in list.GroupBy(x => x.SourceTitle))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < group.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        group.ElementAt(i).Color = palette[counter % 10];                       
                    }
                    counter++;
                }

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
foreach (var x in myList.GroupBy(m => m.SourceTitle).Select((gms, i) => new { gms, i }))
{
    foreach (var m in x.gms)
    {
        m.Color = colorPallete[x.i % colorPallete.Length];
    }
}
```